# Object Follow Mouse Dragging Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object moving forward constantly, I want to make it move on the X axis by mouse dragging any part of the screen (swiping), so I tried this code but when first clicking on the screen the object move to the mouse X position (without dragging)! do you have any suggestions on how to make it move only when dragging?

**The Script:**

```
private bool dragging = false;
private float distance;

public Rigidbody Ball;
public float Speed = 100;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    Ball.velocity = transform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
}


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position);
        dragging = true;
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

    if (dragging)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
        transform.position = new Vector3(rayPoint.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the object you want to move the one this component is attached to? and is that object also the same one the Rigidbody `Ball` is attached to? In that case use [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) instead of setting the position via the `Transform` component!

Comment: @derHugo I've edited the post, check it again please.

Comment: Well now the code is very different ... you didn't answer my question ^^ And .. because you are setting the `draggin` to true on MouseDown (the moment you click) and then set the position. Why did you remove the the `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseDrag` implementation?

Comment: I removed it because I want to move the object when dragging any place on the screen

Comment: Oh I see than let me update my answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

For the continues movement you can use `GetMouseButton` which is true while the button stays pressed (in contrary to `GetMouseButtonDown` which is true only the first frame the button is pressed)

You said the script is attached to the same as the `RigiBody` component. In such a case you should never place an object using

```
transform.position = ...
```

but instead use [RigidBody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) like

```
Ball.MovePosition(new Vector3( ... ));
```

Finally store the initial position on mouse down and than use it as a reference point:

```
Vector3 initialPosition;

void Update()
{
    // called the first time mouse button is pressed
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        initialPosition = transform.position;

        Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(0);

        // Not sure but this might get you a slightly better value for distance
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rayPoint );
    }

    // called while button stays pressed
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
        Ball.MovePosition(initialPosition + new Vector3(rayPoint.x, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

---

Also note that I'm not sure that

```
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    Ball.velocity = transform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

is what you want to do. The usage of `Time.deltaTime` makes not much sense here in my eyes. You either want to set the velocity to a certain speed like

```
Ball.velocity = transform.forward * Speed;
```

or you want to change a position using `Time.deltaTime` to have a smooth movement like

```
Ball.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: It still move without dragging :(

Comment: what would you define as `dragging` than? Maybe I didn't completely understand what you are trying to do yet

Comment: The object still moving to the mouse position when I first click, I want the object to move only when I click+move the mouse.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think I got it now: You want to click anywhere on the screen and than only use the difference between the current value and that intitial mouseDown position. But I'm still not sure ... do you really want to move the object on the global X-axis?

Comment: I used this line "Ball.MovePosition(new Vector3(rayPoint.x + initialPosition.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));" instead of this "Ball.MovePosition(initialPosition + new Vector3(rayPoint.x, 0, 0));" to move it only on X axis, but I still get a weird movement, when clicking and releasing the object move fast on the X axis.

Comment: the first time you click, the object move correctly, but the second time after just clicking the object move, and the next time you click the object move faster ... so the more you click the more the movement become faster and weird.